# AppEngine Ruby on Rails app does not deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I am having issues deploying an app of mine to Google AppEngine. It is currently live on Heroku with no issues, so I dont think the issue is with the app. I emailed back and forth with Google support for a while, and one of the things they had me try was to deploy one of their starter apps. For simplicity sake, I am asking this question from the point of view that I am simply trying to deploy their test application, not my real app.

I have downloaded the hello world app from Github, per Google's instructions.
When I go to deploy, it sticks on a certain step and will not go any further.
I have done a fresh install of the google cloud tools and have made sure to run gcloud init.

I downloaded the app from that URL and am using the included app.yaml

Here is my entire CLI output. It will sit at the same status for HOURS.

Thanks for the help.

--Tim

```
Timothys-MBP:2-hello-world tgwright$ gcloud auth login

Your browser has been opened to visit:



    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=xxxxxx





Saved Application Default Credentials.



You are now logged in as [timothy.xxxxx@gmail.com].

Your current project is [xxx-gae-02].  You can change this setting by running:

  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID

Timothys-MBP:2-hello-world tgwright$ gcloud init

Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.



Settings from your current configuration [default] are:

Your active configuration is: [default]



[app]

suppress_change_warning = true

[core]

account = timothy.xxxxx@gmail.com

disable_usage_reporting = False

project = xxx-gae-02



Pick configuration to use:

 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [default] with new settings 

 [2] Create a new configuration

Please enter your numeric choice:  1



Your current configuration has been set to: [default]



Pick credentials to use:

 [1] timothy.xxxxx@gmail.com

 [2] Log in with new credentials

Please enter your numeric choice:  1



You are now logged in as: [timothy.g.wright@gmail.com]



Pick cloud project to use: 

 [1] [xxx-gae-01]

 [2] [xxxx-cloud01]

Please enter your numeric choice:  1



Your current project has been set to: [xxx-gae-01].



Which compute zone would you like to use as project default?

 [1] [asia-east1-b]

 [2] [asia-east1-a]

 [3] [asia-east1-c]

 [4] [europe-west1-c]

 [5] [europe-west1-d]

 [6] [europe-west1-b]

 [7] [us-central1-c]

 [8] [us-central1-b]

 [9] [us-central1-f]

 [10] [us-central1-a]

 [11] [us-east1-d]

 [12] [us-east1-b]

 [13] [us-east1-c]

 [14] Do not set default zone

Please enter your numeric choice:  9



Your project default compute zone has been set to [us-central1-f].

You can change it by running [gcloud config set compute/zone NAME].



Your project default compute region has been set to [us-central1].

You can change it by running [gcloud config set compute/region NAME].



Do you want to use Google's source hosting (see 

"https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/") (Y/n)?  n





gcloud has now been configured!

You can use [gcloud config] to change more gcloud settings.



Your active configuration is: [default]



[app]

suppress_change_warning = true

[compute]

region = us-central1

zone = us-central1-f

[core]

account = timothy.xxxx@gmail.com

disable_usage_reporting = False

project = xxx-gae-01

Timothys-MBP:2-hello-world tgwright$ gcloud auth list

Credentialed accounts:

 - timothy.xxx@gmail.com (active)



To set the active account, run:

  $ gcloud config set account ``ACCOUNT''



Timothys-MBP:2-hello-world tgwright$ gcloud config list

Your active configuration is: [default]



[app]

suppress_change_warning = true

[compute]

region = us-central1

zone = us-central1-f

[core]

account = timothy.xxxx@gmail.com

disable_usage_reporting = False

project = xxx-gae-01

Timothys-MBP:2-hello-world tgwright$ gcloud preview app deploy --verbosity debug

DEBUG: Running gcloud.preview.app.deploy with Namespace(__calliope_internal_deepest_parser=ArgumentParser(prog='gcloud.preview.app.deploy', usage=None, description="*(BETA)* This command is used to deploy both code and configuration to the App Engine\nserver.  As an input it takes one or more ``DEPLOYABLES'' that should be\nuploaded.  A ``DEPLOYABLE'' can be a module's .yaml file or a configuration's\n.yaml file.", version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=False), account=None, authority_selector=None, authorization_token_file=None, bucket=None, cmd_func=<bound method Command.Run of <googlecloudsdk.calliope.backend.Command object at 0x10e936590>>, command_path=['gcloud', 'preview', 'app', 'deploy'], configuration=None, credential_file_override=None, deployables=[], docker_build=None, document=None, force=False, format=None, h=None, help=None, http_timeout=None, ignore_bad_certs=False, image_url=None, log_http=None, project=None, promote=None, quiet=None, repo_info_file=None, server=None, stop_previous_version=None, trace_email=None, trace_log=False, trace_token=None, user_output_enabled=None, verbosity='debug', version=None).

DEBUG: API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1beta4]

You are about to deploy the following modules:

 - xxx-gae-01/default (from [/Users/tgwright/Google Drive/Sites/2-hello-world/app.yaml])

     Deployed URL: [https://xxx-gae-01.appspot.com]



Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y



Beginning deployment...

DEBUG: Host: appengine.google.com

DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False

DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/vms/prepare?app_id=ebt-gae-01 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=

INFO: Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token

INFO: Refreshing access_token

If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...\DEBUG: Got response: {bucket: vm-containers.xxx-gae-01.appspot.com, path: /containers}



If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.



INFO: Not checking for [go] because runtime is [ruby]
```

Comment: Have you tried deploying a non-Managed-VM app to the same project? e.g. a trivial python or php app?

Comment: @tx802 I was able to deploy the helloworld app for python with no problem.

Comment: @alex-martelli can you offer any help?